# find the value of $f(0)$, given $f(f(x))=0$ has roots as 1 & 2

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics

> find the value of $f(0)$, given $f(f(x))=0$ has roots as 1 & 2, $f(x) = x^2 + \alpha x + \beta$

**My attempt:**

If $k_1$, $k_2$ are the roots of $f(x)$, $f(x) = k_1$ has roots 1 & 2 $\therefore \alpha = -3, \beta-k_1 = 2 \text{ or } \beta-k_2 = 2$ and $f(x) = x^2 -3x+\beta$. I could not proceed further with this approach

Another line of thought is that $f(f(x))$ would be a quartic equation, which means that for it to have 2 roots, it will either have 2 real, 2 imaginary roots or just 2 roots (x-axis would be tangent to this curve at 1 and 2). This information doesn't seem very helpful in solving the problem.

Comment: $f(f(x))$ will have four roots. How do you know both $1$ and $2$ come from $f(x)=k_1$ ? What if $f(1)$ is root of $f(x)=k_1$ and $f(2)$ is root of $f(x)=k_2$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $f(f(x))= (x^2+ax+b)^2 + a(x^2+ax+b) + b$

Put $x=1,x=2$ and set to 0:

$(1+a+b)^2 + a(1+a+b) + b = 0$ **_(i)
$(4+2a+b)^2 + a(4+2a+b) + b =0$ _**(ii)

Subtracting first equation from second yields

$(a+3)(4a+2b+5)=0$

If $a=-3$, then putting value of $a$ in (i) will give a quadratic with no real solutions in $b$.

So, $4a+2b+5=0$

or
    $a=\frac{-5-2b}{4}$

Putting this value in (i) will lead to $b=\frac{-3}{2}$

So, $$f(0)=b=-\frac{3}{2}$$

Comment: With $f(x)=x^2-\frac{3}{4}x-1$, $1$ and $2$ are not roots of $f(f(x))=0$. I got $f(x)=x^2-\frac{x}{2}-\frac{3}{2}$.

Comment: How did you get that? Is there some algebraic mistake in my solution?

Comment: Yes, at the end when you substitute $a$ into (i), you should get $b=-\frac{3}{2}$.

Comment: Thanks, I corrected it.

Comment: Since OP mentions imaginary roots, complex numbers might be taken into account, $b=3\pm i$ gives two more solutions

Answer (score 1):

> $$f(x) = x^2 + \alpha x + \beta$$

Since $f(f(x))=0$ has root at $x=1$ and $x=2$, it implies $f(f(1))=0$ and $f(f(2))=0$

$$f(f(1))=0 \implies f(\alpha + \beta + 1) = 0$$
$$f(f(2))=0 \implies f(2 \alpha + \beta + 4) = 0$$

$\implies f(x)$ has at least $1$ roots $\implies Δ \geq 0$

**Case $1$:** $Δ = 0$

- $f(x) \text{ has only 1 root} \implies \alpha + \beta + 1 = 2 \alpha + \beta + 4 \text{ and } \implies \alpha = -3$
- Then $f(\beta - 2) = 0 \implies (\beta - 2)^2 - 3(\beta - 2) + \beta = 0$ which has 2 imaginary roots: $\beta = 3 \pm i$. Therfore:

> $$f(0) = \beta = 3 \pm i$$

**Case $2$:** $Δ > 0$

- $f(x) \text{ has 2 distinct roots which is } \alpha + \beta + 1 \text{ and } 2 \alpha + \beta + 4$
- By **Vieta's Formula**:

$$(\alpha + \beta + 1) + (2 \alpha + \beta + 4) = -\alpha \text{ (1) }$$
$$(\alpha + \beta + 1) \cdot (2 \alpha + \beta + 4) = \beta \text{ (2) }$$

$\text{(1) } \implies 4\alpha + 2\beta + 5 = 0 \implies 2 \alpha + \beta + 4 = \frac{3}{2} \text{(1')}$

Substitute $(1')$ into $(2)$:

$\text{(2) } \implies \alpha + \beta + 1 = \frac{2}{3} \beta \implies \alpha + \frac{1}{3} \beta + 1 = 0 \text{ (2')}$

Solving $(1')$ and $(2')$ to get:

> $$\alpha = -\frac{1}{2}, \beta = -\frac{3}{2}$$

Therefore:

> $$f(0) = \beta = -\frac{3}{2}$$